# How do I flag a post that I already flag retracted?

Tags: support, flags

I asked this question on stack overflow:

[Remove whitespace around string Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767822/remove-whitespace-around-string-java)

I later reviewed the question, and it was a duplicate of:

[How do I remove whitespace at the beginning of my string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883152/how-do-i-remove-whitespace-at-the-beginning-of-my-string/)

I flagged my post as duplicate, then I searched for the duplicate post. I couldn't find it, so I tried using the question ID. I wasn't quite sure what that was, so I tried using the number 8883152 (It worked, but I didn't know that). I retracted the flag in case I marked it as duplicate of some random post, but now that I realize that it worked, how do I flag it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot flag a question for closure more than once.

The best you can do is comment that you intended the question to be closed as a duplicate of that question (and provide a link) and hope that others see it and vote to close the question.

Comment: What is the reason for this? I have accidentally flagged a question using the wrong flagging option, then tried to go back later to correct my mistake. Only to find that it won't let me re-flag the question. Is there a reason for preventing users from correcting a mistake made when flagging?